# I want to copy a formula which ends in a number, but amend the number in the new formula by a fixed value

Tags: excel-formula

In Cell F190 I have the following formula: ='[Account 19617768.xlsx]19617768'!$G$1142   (the cell displays the value in 19617768 $G$1142 - (£1609.50)
I can display this formula in Cell J190 with the formula: =FORMULATEXT(F190)
By manipulating FORMULATEXT(F190) (i.e. Using Left(FORMULATEXT(F190),38)&(Right(FORMULATEXT(F190),4)+2), I end up with Cell J190 displaying formula: ='[Account19617768.xlsx]19617768'!$G$1144.
What I need is for Cell J190 NOT to display the formula, but the actual value in Account19617768.xlsx G1144 (£1859.50), and it's the conversion of the formula into the value I don't seem to be able to find an appropriate function
I don't have a problem if I need to use an additional function in another cell to finish off the conversion?

I know this should be easy, but having just been released from hospital, I seem to be having
trouble working the simplest things out

Comment: You want to drag it to cells below it or to the right?

Comment: I have obviously not made myself clear, so i have edited the original query

Answer (score 0):

'$' signs in excel formula keep the preceding data static.

In other words. Remove the $ in G$1065.

Now when you drag the formula down the column the Cell number will increase.

If you keep the $ in front of G the column G will never change no matter where the formula is copied.